# Align WPF window on startup

Tags: wpf, window

I have a `WPF` window which is positioned incorrectly when shown.

[image: How it looks now]

I want it to be positioned correctly, like this:

[image: How I want it to look]

How may I accomplish this?

This is the `xaml` for the window:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1050" Width="910" Background="{x:Null}"  >
```

Comment: I can't look at either link because I'm in work. Also, if the links disappear then this question is no longer understandable. If you can put the images in the question, or increase the verbiage to explain the problem better, then the question will be of much higher quality.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to put the images, that's why there are display using links.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very handy XAML tag called [WindowStartupLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to specify where it starts. It is used like this:

```
<Window
 ...
 Title="MainWindow" 
 Height="1050" 
 Width="910" 
 Background="{x:Null}"
 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
```

This will start it in the center of the window where the mouse pointer is.

Edit: There is also an option called CenterOwner if you want it to always be the same monitor you start your app on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (it will bind the top of your window to the top of the screen):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1050" Width="910" Background="{x:Null}"  WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Top="0">
```